# Possible Async Call in a Conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm refactoring some legacy code that I didn't originally write and I've come upon an issue with asynchronous data loading. The first time a particular modal is opened, a bunch of data representing a form object gets loaded. A function then cycles through the inputs of the form and fleshes them out as needed. It looks something like this (extremely simplified):

```
component.inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.field == 'foo') {
        input.cols = 5;
        //etc.
    }

    if (input.field == 'bar') {
        DataService.getBars().then(function(data){
            data.forEach(function(e){
                input.options.push(e.description);
            });
        };
    }

    if (input.field == 'baz') {
        input.pattern = /regex/;
        //etc.
    }
});

return component;
```

The problem, of course, is that if my input.field is 'bar', the code continues running and hits the final return before the async call to DataService is resolved, so the first time the modal is opened, the input.options have not been filled out for 'bar' input.

Is it possible to make the code wait for the promise from the DataService to be resolved before continuing, or is there another way to handle the situation where in most cases the function is synchronous, but has to make an async call in only one case? Or have I shot myself in the foot by including an async call in this big chain of ifs?

Comment: The real issue here is that you should be making ONE restful call to return all potential data needed.  Once you have the data, you should then proceed with the mapping and finally, return the modal.

Comment: @David L. An interesting point. I suppose I could wrap the whole function inside the .then of the DataService call, but then we have to make the call whether or not that data is needed. Plus the method is quite large (the example above being a huge simplification) so it would be awkward and not human-friendly.

Comment: I'd change the object structure so that if you didn't need to make the call, you wouldn't.  As it exists now you have a tremendous inefficiency in this modal pop.

Comment: If you don't care about <ie9 (I think) you might be interested by the Promise object. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a promise and attach it as a property to your returned object.

```
function getComponent() {
    component.inputs.forEach(function(input) {
        //create initial promise
        var $promise = $q.when(input);
        if (input.field == 'foo') {
            input.cols = 5;
            //etc.
        }
        if (input.field == 'bar') {
            //chain from initial promise
            $promise = $promise.then(function () {
                 //return promise for chaining
                 return getBarPromise(input);
            });
        }
        //attach promise to input object
        input.$promise = $promise;
    });

    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(inputs, function(input) {
        promises.push(input.$promise);
    });
    //create composite promise
    var $promise = $q.all(promises);

    //final chain 
    $promise = $promise.then( function() {
         //return component for chaining
         return component;
    });
    //attach promise to component  
    component.$promise = $promise;

    return component;
};
```

The returned `component` object will eventually be filled in with the results of the service calls. Functions that need to wait for completion of all the service calls can **chain** from the attached `$promise` property.

```
$scope.component = getComponent();

$scope.component.$promise.then( function (resolvedComponent) {
    //open modal 
}).catch( function(errorResponse) {
    //log error response
});
```

Because calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with your existing code structure and make this work, you probably will need to use `promises`. You can also use javascript's `map function`. Note: you would need to inject `$q` into wherever you want to call this function.

```
function getComponent() {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        deferred2 = $q.defer(),
        promises = component.inputs.map(function(input)) {
            if (input.field == 'foo') {
                input.cols = 5;
                deferred2.resolve();
            }
            else if (input.field == 'bar') {
                DataService.getBars().then(function(data) {
                    data.forEach(function(e){
                        input.options.push(e.description);
                    });
                    deferred2.resolve();
                }).catch(function(err)) {
                    deferred2.reject(err);
                });
            }
            else if (input.field == 'baz') {
                input.pattern = /regex/;
                deferred2.resolve();
            }

            return deferred2.promise;
        });

    $q.all(promises)
        .then(function() {
            deferred.resolve(component);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Once each `input` in `component.inputs` has been parsed appropriately, then the `$q.all` block will trigger and you can return your new `component` object.
Finally, to set your `component` object, simply do the following:

```
getComponent().then(function(result)) {
        //Set component object here with result
        $scope.component = result;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```